# C/HTML: Correctly printing the username and password input of the user

Tags: html, c, forms, cgi

I started experimenting with C/CGI/HTML a few days ago. I was piqued by some log-in page program that I saw so I tried to do my own:

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *data;
  char *user;
  char *password;
  printf("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
  printf("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>");
  data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  if (data) {
    sscanf(data,"user=%s&password=%s", user, password);
    printf("Hello Mr./Ms. %s\n",user);
    printf("You entered your password %s\n",password);
  }
  printf("<form action='http://localhost/10.html'>");
  printf("<input type=text name=user>");
  printf("<input type=password name =password>");
  printf("</body></html>");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

And whenever I execute my HTML file:

with an input of:

username = 123
password = 123

This is the output that this program gives me:

```
 Hello Mr./Ms. 123&password=123 You entered your password (null)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Which input ? The only input into this program comes from the environnment variable `QUERY_STRING` and you didn't mention what this environnment variable contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your piece of code

```
char *user;
char *password;
```

`user` and `password` are just uninitialized pointers.

You need this:

```
char user[100];
char password[100];
```

But there are most likely other CGI and sscanf related problems.